# Get Current row from Gridview

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I am new at programming and I'm trying to upload an image and save it in folder with the current product id. However when I update the image a new folder is created. How can I check the selected Gridview row and check if the id is not null then replace image and if is null upload?

I know the idea of getting max(id) and setting to the folder name isn't a good practice but I wanted the images separated by id.Here goes the code.

```
        private void upload_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog opFile = new OpenFileDialog();
            opFile.Title = "Select image for this product";
            opFile.Filter = "jpg files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (opFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
            try
            {
                string iName = opFile.FileName;
                var dir = @"images/" + GetCurrentId();
                var path = Path.Combine(dir, Path.GetFileName(iName));

                if (!Directory.Exists(dir) &&(produto)this.tbprodutoBindingSource.Current == null))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
                }

                File.Copy(iName, path);
            }
               catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to open file " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            opFile.Dispose();
        }
            }

        private int GetCurrentId()
        {
            var result = dataContextFactory.DataContext.produtos.Max(x => x.id_produto);
            int maxId = Convert.ToInt32(result);
            if (maxId == 0) maxId = 1;
            else
                maxId++;

            return maxId;

        }
```

Comment: You always return `maxId++` whether the ID exists or not; that cannot work. You need to store ID in your `DataContext` and return that if it exists. If it doesn't exist you have to create a new record and return the newly-created ID (which may not be maxId + 1).

Comment: Any example of how I do that??

Comment: Because rigth now all I do is addnew to the bindingsource and then EndEdit(), finally submitchanges to the conection. How can I get the Id, if I'm doing throghout the griedview?